# Chart JS datalabel in bar chart background and text are the same color

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am working with angular and chart js, I am putting labels inside the bars with a background for better contrast,

It works perfect in doughnut chart, but when I tried the same configuration in a bar chart the font color and the background color are set to the same.
Do you have any idea what can I do?
[My chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuEke.png)

```
 plugins: {
  legend: {
    position: 'right',
    labels: {
      font: {
        size: 3,
      },
    },
  },
  datalabels: {
    clamp: true,
    display: true,
    formatter: (val, ctx) => {
      return ctx.chart.data.labels[val.dataIndex];
    },
    color: 'black',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 2,

    font: {
      weight: 'bold',
    },
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(253, 253, 253)',
  },
},
```

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/9oj6fatv/

Comment: Thank you, i couldn't figure out why my code doesn't work, but yours works perfect!